# start an application based on extension not protocol (using xdg-open)

Tags: gnome, xdg-open

When I do

```
xdg-open demo.odt
```

Libre Office opens - as it should. When I do

```
xdg-open http://askubuntu.com
```

my browser opens - as it should. But now I'd like to have a command where I do

mime-based-xdg-open http://www.someserver/demo.odt

and Libre Office would open with the URL on the command line. Is there a way to figure out what xdg-open would use for a specific extension or mime-type? Then I could construct a script that does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
xdg-mime query default MIMETYPE
```

to get your desktop's default app for opening files with mime-type `MIMETYPE`

To get the mime-type of file `FILE` (not an URL) use

```
xdg-mime query filetype FILE
```